# Neovim - gf equivalent but for an adjacent, existing split

Tags: vim, split-window, neovim

My typical workflow involves having a large "main" split, with a smaller split below for a terminal. When I get a stack trace, I'd like to be able to use `gf` to go to that location in the main split.

However, `gf` will open it in the same split as the terminal. Other options exist, e.g. `<C-w>f`, but these create new splits. Instead, I want to be able to open this file path in "the other split".

I'm struggling to express the concept of "the other split" in a way (neo)vim understands.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>C-W</kbd><kbd>gf</kbd> - Edit existing file under cursor in new tabpage

That may do the job, it closes the terminal for me though